# Deploy WAR in Tomcat on Kubernetes

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, kubernetes

I need to create a Multibranch Jenkins job to deploy a .war file in Tomcat that should run on Kubernetes. Basically, I need the following:

1. A way to install Tomcat on Kubernetes platform.
2. Deploy my war file on this newly installed Tomcat.

I need to make use of `Dockerfile` to make this happen.

PS: I am very new to Kubernetes and Docker stuff and need basic details as well. I tried finding tutorials but couldn't get any satisfactory article.

Any help will be highly highly appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Docker part

You can use the [tomcat docker official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat)

In your `Dockerfile` just copy your war file in `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/` directory :

```
FROM tomcat

COPY app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

Build it :

`docker build --no-cache -t <REGISTRY>/<IMAGE>:<TAG> .`

Once your image is built, push it into a Docker registry of your choice.

`docker push <REGISTRY>/<IMAGE>:<TAG>`

### Kubernetes part

1) Here is a simple kubernetes [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) for your tomcat image

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-deployment
  labels:
    app: tomcat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: <REGISTRY>/<IMAGE>:<TAG>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

This Deployment definition will create a pod based on your tomcat image.

Put it in a yml file and execute `kubectl create -f yourfile.yml` to create it.

2) Create a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) :

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: tomcat-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: tomcat
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

You can now access your pod inside the cluster with http://tomcat-service.your-namespace/app (because your war is called `app.war`)

3) If you have [Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-controllers), you can create an [Ingress ressource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource) to expose the application outside the cluster :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tomcat-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /app
        backend:
          serviceName: tomcat-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Now access the application using http://ingress-controller-ip/app

Comment: Hi @Nicolas, Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried implementing this and at the end of the Jenkins Job, I am getting this:

+ kubectl --kubeconfig **** --namespace=dev-a apply -f k8s/services/
service "tomcat-service" created
[Pipeline] sh
+ kubectl --kubeconfig **** --namespace=dev-a apply -f k8s/dev/
ingress "tomcat-ingress" created

However, I don't see any new pod created when I run this:
kubectl --kubeconfig=dev.us-east-1 --namespace=dev-a get pods

Comment: Something is getting wrong probably. Type `kube get events --sort-by lastTimestamp --namespace=dev-a` to check the events relative to the new components created

Comment: should the ingress content and the deployment file be placed in different yaml?

Comment: no you can put all in one yaml file. Check this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/blob/master/guestbook/all-in-one/guestbook-all-in-one.yaml)

Comment: The build is getting executed successfully but I am getting ImagePullBackOff error in pod. On describing the pod, I found this error:  pull access denied for xyz/myrepo, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.

However, I can see the image getting pushed with the same name. I also tried docker login but it didn't work.

Comment: If you regsitry is secured, you need to create [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-secret-in-the-cluster-that-holds-your-authorization-token). After its creation, you need to [reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-pod-that-uses-your-secret) the secret in your Deployment with `imagePullSecrets` instruction.